# Clickhouse - how do I do Natural sort query with limit?

Tags: clickhouse, natural-sort

I want my select queries able to do natural sort using these concepts: https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Natural_sorting

Answer (score 1):

You can play with [collation settings](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-collation.html#Collation_Settings) like in the query below.

Take into account that ClickHouse has the [collation bug#7482](https://github.com/ClickHouse/ClickHouse/issues/7482) and fails for some languages such as *en*, *de*.

```sql
SELECT arrayJoin(['kk 50', 'KK 01', '    KK 2', '  KK    3', 'kk 1', 'x9y99', 'x9y100']) item
ORDER BY item ASC
/*
Result:

┌─item──────┐
│     KK 2  │
│   KK    3 │
│ KK 01     │
│ kk 1      │
│ kk 50     │
│ x9y100    │
│ x9y99     │
└───────────┘
*/


SELECT arrayJoin(['kk 50', 'KK 01', '    KK 2', '  KK    3', 'kk 1', 'x9y99', 'x9y100']) item
ORDER BY item ASC COLLATE 'tr-u-kn-true-ka-shifted'
/*
Result:

┌─item──────┐
│ kk 1      │
│ KK 01     │
│     KK 2  │
│   KK    3 │
│ kk 50     │
│ x9y99     │
│ x9y100    │
└───────────┘
*/
```